# Perlbrew for perl6

Tags: raku

Is here something as `perlbrew` for the `perl6`, or the recommended installation method is as it is described in the

- http://raku.org/getting-started/ and
- http://rakudo.org/how-to-get-rakudo/

ps: using OS X

Comment: see https://github.com/tadzik/rakudobrew

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is probably what you want for the near future–[rakudobrew](https://github.com/tadzik/rakudobrew). I’m using it on OS X 10.8–10 without any trouble at all (well, some of the C/image stuff won’t build for me—I wanted to do the [space invaders](https://ttjjss.wordpress.com/2014/05/11/new-game-space-invaders/)—but everything else is great and easy).

Oh, I missed Christoph’s comment; sorry. To add value to the proposition, I’ll also suggest [panda](https://github.com/tadzik/panda), a cpanm-lite-like tool to work with some of the better available [perl6 modules](http://modules.perl6.org/).

Comment: zef is the new panda

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Rakudo website](http://rakudo.org/how-to-get-rakudo/#Discouraged-Tools) both `rakudobrew` and `panda` are **discouraged**.

[zef](https://github.com/ugexe/zef) seems to be the preferred tool for module management and it is also referenced from the [Perl 6 Documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/language/modules.html).

Answer (score 3):

One comment on the [How to get rakudo](http://rakudo.org/how-to-get-rakudo/#comment-712) is Mac OS specific:

```
Rajeev Jha says:    
2011.11.01 at 18:28 

Here are the instructions for building on mac osx lion
create a new dir, say nuke and cd to it (xcode should be installed)

1. wget https://github.com/downloads/rakudo/star/rakudo-star-2011.07.tar.gz
2. tar -zxvf rakudo-star-2011.07.tar.gz
3. cd rakudo-star-2011.07
4. perl Configure.pl –gen-moar
5. make
6. make install

Run perl6 from nuke/rakudo-star-2011.07/perl6
```

For part 1 use the [newest file you find](http://rakudo.org/downloads/star/) instead of a version from 2011.

Comment: Parrot support will be suspended - you probably want `--gen-moar` instead

Comment: @Christoph Thats a shame. I had big hopes for Parrot :-(

Comment: Parrot support *might* get resurrected after the 6.0 release; the priority right now is getting that out on MoarVM, with JVM next in line

Comment: Possibly, if someone proves rurban's controversial claim that Parrot threads are significantly more performant than MoarVM's for P6 semantics and Rakudo/NQP, Parrot will make a major come back.

Comment: @Christoph, Parrot won"t be resurrected (typing this mid 2018).

Answer (score 3):

I just use brew on macOS, thusly:

```
brew install rakudo-star
zef install Inline::Perl5
```

Comment: What directories should I add to $PATH after that?

Answer (score 2):

[Rakudup](https://github.com/rakudup/rakudup.github.io) has been recently released, too. Check out [its site](https://rakudup.github.io)